# User Logged onto Windows

Tags: c#

I created a Windows Service that Tracks which App Server a user is actually connected to through a load balancer.

It retrieves the user that is logged into windows on that machine, then cross references the Active Directory (AD) account to return the first name, last name and E-mail (for notification through the website created for this project)

There is one system on the Network where users only remote into the system, the Vista System, for some reason it is returning with Values that say "LOCAL SERVICE" is Logged into that machine, it's weird and the Security Guys say that it is impossible for the "LOCAL SERVICE" account to be logged into Windows.

Here is how I get the user that is logged into Windows

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from win32_computersystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, query);

foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    _username = mo["username"].ToString();
}
// remove the domain part from the username
string[] usernameParts = _username.Split('\\');
_username = usernameParts[usernameParts.Length - 1];
```

I only post this because, it isn't broken, **it does exactly what it is supposed to**.

is this an Edge Case that I can fix, or is the user actually "logged in" to this machine

Is there something that I can do to make this code more efficient?

<s>I have cross posted this on SuperUser</s> [Migrated cross post to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26623110/1214743)

Comment: I'm fairly certain this isn't the problem (hence comment instead of answer), but `ManagementObjectSearcher` implements `IDisposable` and therefore its creation and lifetime should be wrapped in a `using` clause.

Comment: By the by, this may explain the odd results and provide a solution (it uses PowerShell, but should be able to be converted to C#): http://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/01/quick-hit-find-currently-logged-on-users/

Comment: The very first problem is that your query selects all from the win32_computersystem, which is not the same as selecting logged in users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my second comment, below is a possible solution. This solution involves a different querying method that will work for both console sessions and remote sessions. This method looks at all processes that are the explore.exe process, which is the user shell for each user that is logged into the server.  Once armed with the list of those processes, getting the owner for it is another WMI query (`GetProcessOwner` method).

```
// what to do if multiple users logged in?
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
{
    _username = GetProcessOwner(p.Id);
}

// remove the domain part from the username
var usernameParts = _username.Split('\\');

_username = usernameParts[usernameParts.Length - 1];
```

...

```
    public static string GetProcessOwner(int processId)
    {
        var query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
        ManagementObjectCollection processList;

        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
        {
            processList = searcher.Get();
        }

        foreach (var mo in processList.OfType<ManagementObject>())
        {
            object[] argList = { string.Empty, string.Empty };
            var returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));

            if (returnVal == 0)
            {
                // return DOMAIN\user
                return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
            }
        }

        return "NO OWNER";
    }
```

Comment: so I should use the application that uses load balancing and find out who owns it. I think that I need to restructure my service so that it doesn't bother the table when the application isn't open as well. hopefully I can get all this into the current update before this weekend....

Comment: could you throw a little explanation on this answer, so if anyone else happens on this that doesn't have an intimate knowledge of what is going here will have a pointer to get them rolling in the right direction.

Comment: Added some explanation to show the methodology behind what's going on.

Comment: will this see other users logged onto the system?

Comment: If the process running this has admin rights on the box, then I believe it will.

Comment: I actually use `GetProcessByName` already to count how many applications are open, so I can just create a variable and grab both from it.

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work, it was returning null for everything in the `argList` and `returnVal` always had more than 0, I tried it with more than 0 and that is when I saw that it was returning nulls in the `argList` variable.

Comment: Yikes! I guess the process you were running under didn't have permission to query for owner then.